# Database permissions with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions

Is it possible to restrict user access to a postgresql database by specifying a database, rather than a table?

I understand that the line:

```
GRANT ALL ON tableName TO joeuser
```

enables this user to access this table and do anything they want. However I want to allow a user access to the database `databaseName` that contains `tableName` (and all tables within `databaseName`), but not all databases on my postgresql server.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, no. Granting privileges to a database:

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE databaseName TO joeuser;
```

does not automatically grant privileges on objects in the database; and granting privileges on every object that's currently in the database won't automatically grant privileges on any future objects that might be created.

Comment: Thanks @ruakh. I want the user to be able to create tables also; so I suppose I have to allow them full access to the server.

Comment: @celenius: Actually, the ability to create tables probably won't be a problem for you; for that, you just need to give joeuser the CREATE privilege on a schema, and then (s)he can create tables on that schema. The problem is just with giving him/her access to tables (and schemata) created by other users.

Comment: By the way, you may find http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-grant.html helpful, whatever approach you take.

Comment: Does that mean that I need to create a new schema, other than `public`? At the moment I'm just using the default setting.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you want. It might be that you're trying to find a single SQL statement that handles all your privileges now and forever more. SQL privileges generally don't work that way.

Depending on the version, you can control *connection* to the database in two ways.

- By editing pg_hba.conf. (Probably not suitable in your case.)
- By a [GRANT (or REVOKE) CONNECT ON DATABASE...](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) statement. (Since version 8.2.)

You can [change the default privileges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) for tables, views, sequences, and functions. (Version 9.0+)

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` is a PostgreSQL extension to SQL.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for one SQL statement to do this. What I want is to allow a user to have full permissions on one database on a server, and not be able to edit any of the other databases on that server. I'm not able to control it via `pg_hba.conf` as I can't control for the ip address.

Comment: To get full permissions on tables, views, sequences, and functions, you can create a new database, change the default permissions, disconnect the old database from all users, load all its objects into the new database, rename the old database (drop it later), and rename the new one.  You might need to REVOKE CONNECT on the other databases. There are probably several "gotchas" in that, since I'm suggesting the idea without testing it. Do test it yourself, and let us know how that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON DataBase.TableName TO User;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).